# Trouble getting my bluetooth headset as audio output Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: bluetooth

I just bought a bluetooth headset. Achieve pair and connect to the computer with blueman.

The problem gives me the time to change the sound settings, first I do not get the headphones to select as an output option but with the command: pulseaudio-k, succeeds in making it to appear, but when you select it will not let me save configuration simply does nothing, as he had not selected headphones and speakers selected again.

[image: screenshot]

**pacmd list:**

```
1 sink(s) available.
  *** index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9959
    volume: 0:  52% 1:  52%
            0: -17,04 dB 1: -17,04 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 100%
                 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Estéreo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 371,52 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 5
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "92HD99BXX Analog"
        alsa.id = "92HD99BXX Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xc2700000 irq 51"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "1c20"
        device.product.name = "6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Estéreo analógico"
        device.description = "Audio Interno Estéreo analógico"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Intel CougarPoint HDMI"
        alsa.components = "HDA:111d76e5,103c17f8,00100102 HDA:80862805,80860101,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Altavoces (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Auriculares analógicos (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
2 source(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 1950
    volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%
            0: 0,00 dB 1: 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 100%
                 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Estéreo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 371,52 ms
    monitor_of: 0
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 5
    properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Audio Interno Estéreo analógico"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xc2700000 irq 51"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "1c20"
        device.product.name = "6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
  * index: 1
    name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9959
    volume: 0:  24% 1:  24%
            0: -36,74 dB 1: -36,74 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume:  10%
                 -60,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 1,01 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Estéreo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 20,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 371,52 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 5
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "92HD99BXX Analog"
        alsa.id = "92HD99BXX Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xc2700000 irq 51"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "1c20"
        device.product.name = "6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Estéreo analógico"
        device.description = "Audio Interno Estéreo analógico"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Intel CougarPoint HDMI"
        alsa.components = "HDA:111d76e5,103c17f8,00100102 HDA:80862805,80860101,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-input-microphone-internal: Micrófono interno (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-microphone: Micrófono (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    active port: <analog-input-microphone-internal>
7 client(s) logged in.
    index: 0
    driver: <module-systemd-login.c>
    owner module: 17
    properties:
        application.name = "Login Session c2"
        systemd-login.session = "c2"
    index: 1
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 10
    properties:
        application.name = "Ubuntu Audio Settings"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "28"
        application.id = "com.canonical.settings.sound"
        application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"
        application.version = "0.1"
        application.process.id = "2364"
        application.process.user = "steven"
        application.process.host = "linux-HP"
        application.process.binary = "indicator-sound-service"
        application.language = "es_GT.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "6bf66e30c3f3f846367c005c5178879b"
        application.process.session_id = "c2"
    index: 2
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 10
    properties:
        application.name = "GNOME Volume Control Dialog"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "28"
        application.id = "org.gnome.VolumeControl"
        application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"
        application.version = "3.6.3"
        application.process.id = "5906"
        application.process.user = "steven"
        application.process.host = "linux-HP"
        application.process.binary = "gnome-control-center"
        application.language = "es_GT.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "6bf66e30c3f3f846367c005c5178879b"
        application.process.session_id = "c2"
    index: 3
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 10
    properties:
        application.name = "Blueman"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "28"
        application.process.id = "4822"
        application.process.user = "steven"
        application.process.host = "linux-HP"
        application.process.binary = "python2.7"
        application.language = "es_GT.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "6bf66e30c3f3f846367c005c5178879b"
        application.process.session_id = "c2"
        application.icon_name = "/usr/share/pixmaps/python2.7.xpm"
    index: 4
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 10
    properties:
        application.name = "Blueman"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "28"
        application.process.id = "2459"
        application.process.user = "steven"
        application.process.host = "linux-HP"
        application.process.binary = "python2.7"
        application.language = "es_GT.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "6bf66e30c3f3f846367c005c5178879b"
        application.process.session_id = "c2"
        application.icon_name = "/usr/share/pixmaps/python2.7.xpm"
    index: 5
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 10
    properties:
        application.name = "GNOME Volume Control Media Keys"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "28"
        application.id = "org.gnome.VolumeControl"
        application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"
        application.version = "3.8.5"
        application.process.id = "2115"
        application.process.user = "steven"
        application.process.host = "linux-HP"
        application.process.binary = "gnome-settings-daemon"
        application.language = "es_GT.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "6bf66e30c3f3f846367c005c5178879b"
        application.process.session_id = "c2"
    index: 9
    driver: <cli.c>
    owner module: 23
    properties:
        application.name = "UNIX socket client"
2 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 5
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xc2700000 irq 51"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "1c20"
        device.product.name = "6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Audio Interno"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Estéreo analógico Entrada (priority 60, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo: Estéreo analógico Salida (priority 6000, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Estéreo Analógico Dúplex (priority 6060, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Salida (priority 5400, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Salida + Estéreo analógico Entrada (priority 5460, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Salida (priority 300, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Salida + Estéreo analógico Entrada (priority 360, available: unknown)
        off: Apagado (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#0: Audio Interno Estéreo analógico
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor/#0: Monitor of Audio Interno Estéreo analógico
        alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#1: Audio Interno Estéreo analógico
    ports:
        analog-input-microphone-internal: Micrófono interno (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-microphone: Micrófono (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-output-speaker: Altavoces (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Auriculares analógicos (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    index: 1
    name: <bluez_card.00_13_09_00_1B_CA>
    driver: <module-bluetooth-device.c>
    owner module: 22
    properties:
        device.description = "SWAGE-RB"
        device.string = "00:13:09:00:1B:CA"
        device.api = "bluez"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/502/hci0/dev_00_13_09_00_1B_CA"
        bluez.class = "0x240404"
        bluez.name = "SWAGE-RB"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
        device.intended_roles = "phone"
    profiles:
        hsp: Telefonía Duplex (HSP/HFP) (priority 20, available: unknown)
        a2dp: Reproducción de Alta Fidelidad (A2DP) (priority 10, available: unknown)
        off: Apagado (priority 0, available: yes)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        headset-output: Auriculares (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:

        headset-input: Auriculares (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:

0 sink input(s) available.
1 source outputs(s) available.
    index: 0
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    flags: DONT_MOVE 
    state: RUNNING
    source: 1 <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    volume: 0: 100%
            0: 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    requested latency: 20,00 ms
    sample spec: float32le 1ch 25Hz
    channel map: mono
                 Mono
    resample method: peaks
    owner module: 10
    client: 2 <GNOME Volume Control Dialog>
    properties:
        application.id = "org.gnome.VolumeControl"
        media.name = "Detección de picos"
        application.name = "GNOME Volume Control Dialog"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "28"
        application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"
        application.version = "3.6.3"
        application.process.id = "5906"
        application.process.user = "steven"
        application.process.host = "linux-HP"
        application.process.binary = "gnome-control-center"
        application.language = "es_GT.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "6bf66e30c3f3f846367c005c5178879b"
        application.process.session_id = "c2"
        module-stream-restore.id = "source-output-by-application-id:org.gnome.VolumeControl"
0 cache entrie(s) available.**
```

**/etc/pulse/default.pa:**

```
#!/usr/bin/pulseaudio -nF
#
# This file is part of PulseAudio.
#
# PulseAudio is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# PulseAudio is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
# WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
# General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
# along with PulseAudio; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
# Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307 USA.

# This startup script is used only if PulseAudio is started per-user
# (i.e. not in system mode)

.nofail

### Load something into the sample cache
#load-sample-lazy x11-bell /usr/share/sounds/gtk-events/activate.wav
#load-sample-lazy pulse-hotplug /usr/share/sounds/startup3.wav
#load-sample-lazy pulse-coldplug /usr/share/sounds/startup3.wav
#load-sample-lazy pulse-access /usr/share/sounds/generic.wav

.fail

### Automatically restore the volume of streams and devices
load-module module-device-restore
load-module module-stream-restore
load-module module-card-restore

### Automatically augment property information from .desktop files
### stored in /usr/share/application
load-module module-augment-properties

### Should be after module-*-restore but before module-*-detect
load-module module-switch-on-port-available

### Load audio drivers statically
### (it's probably better to not load these drivers manually, but instead
### use module-udev-detect -- see below -- for doing this automatically)
#load-module module-alsa-sink
#load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0
#load-module module-oss device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input
#load-module module-oss-mmap device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input
#load-module module-null-sink
#load-module module-pipe-sink

### Automatically load driver modules depending on the hardware available
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
load-module module-udev-detect
.else
### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev support)
load-module module-detect
.endif

.ifexists module-android-audio-hal.so
load-module module-android-audio-hal
.endif

### Automatically connect sink and source if JACK server is present
.ifexists module-jackdbus-detect.so
.nofail
load-module module-jackdbus-detect channels=2
.fail
.endif

### Automatically load driver modules for Bluetooth hardware
.ifexists module-bluetooth-policy.so
load-module module-bluetooth-policy
.endif

.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
.endif

### Load several protocols
.ifexists module-esound-protocol-unix.so
load-module module-esound-protocol-unix
.endif
load-module module-native-protocol-unix

### Network access (may be configured with paprefs, so leave this commented
### here if you plan to use paprefs)
#load-module module-esound-protocol-tcp
#load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
#load-module module-zeroconf-publish

### Load the RTP receiver module (also configured via paprefs, see above)
#load-module module-rtp-recv

### Load the RTP sender module (also configured via paprefs, see above)
#load-module module-null-sink sink_name=rtp format=s16be channels=2 rate=44100 sink_properties="device.description='RTP Multicast Sink'"
#load-module module-rtp-send source=rtp.monitor

### Load additional modules from GConf settings. This can be configured with the paprefs tool.
### Please keep in mind that the modules configured by paprefs might conflict with manually
### loaded modules.
.ifexists module-gconf.so
.nofail
load-module module-gconf
.fail
.endif

### Automatically restore the default sink/source when changed by the user
### during runtime
### NOTE: This should be loaded as early as possible so that subsequent modules
### that look up the default sink/source get the right value
load-module module-default-device-restore

### Automatically move streams to the default sink if the sink they are
### connected to dies, similar for sources
load-module module-rescue-streams

### Make sure we always have a sink around, even if it is a null sink.
load-module module-always-sink

### Honour intended role device property
load-module module-intended-roles

### Automatically suspend sinks/sources that become idle for too long
load-module module-suspend-on-idle

### If autoexit on idle is enabled we want to make sure we only quit
### when no local session needs us anymore.
.ifexists module-console-kit.so
load-module module-console-kit
.endif
.ifexists module-systemd-login.so
load-module module-systemd-login
.endif

### Enable positioned event sounds
load-module module-position-event-sounds

### Cork music/video streams when a phone stream is active
#load-module module-role-cork

### Modules to allow autoloading of filters (such as echo cancellation)
### on demand. module-filter-heuristics tries to determine what filters
### make sense, and module-filter-apply does the heavy-lifting of
### loading modules and rerouting streams.
load-module module-filter-heuristics
load-module module-filter-apply

# X11 modules should not be started from default.pa so that one daemon
# can be shared by multiple sessions.

### Load X11 bell module
#load-module module-x11-bell sample=bell-windowing-system

### Register ourselves in the X11 session manager
#load-module module-x11-xsmp

### Publish connection data in the X11 root window
#.ifexists module-x11-publish.so
#.nofail
#load-module module-x11-publish
#.fail
#.endif

### Make some devices default
#set-default-sink output
#set-default-source input

#Nuevo
load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

**bluez-test-audio:**

```
Usage: /usr/bin/bluez-test-audio <command>

    connect <bdaddr>
    disconnect <bdaddr>
```

Comment: The hearphones seems to be working from here, you sure is not? Try testing the sound.

Comment: Yes, I tried that but my speakers sound instead of my headset.

Comment: Could you add the output of `pacmd list`, `cat /etc/pulse/default.pa` and `bluez-test-audio`?

Comment: @Braiam I added it.